# При прокрутке страницы не отображается движение маршрута

Tags: svg, canvas, прокрутка

Поставлена следующая задача:

При прокрутке страницы вниз по мере прочтения контента на заднем фоне должен прокладываться определенный маршрут по карте с помощью canvas и svg.

Кажется, всё сделано, но по какой-то причине карта не отображается. Где может быть ошибка?

Посмотрите и поправьте меня, пожалуйста. Благодарю!

Файлы JS добавил как внешнюю библиотеку. 
Путь к файлу svg прописан в script_app.js

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container canvas {
  background: #b1efff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 990px;
}

.text section {
  min-height: 800px;
}

.title-up {
  display: block;
}

.title-down {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/jquery.waitforimages.js"></script>
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/script_water.js"></script>
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/script_app.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">К</span><span class="title-down">Начало путешествия</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>К</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">Ф</span><span class="title-down">Ф</span></h2>
        <h3>Д</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>К</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">С</span><span class="title-down">Г</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>С</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">Б</span><span class="title-down">Б</span></h2>
        <h3>П</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>М</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">А</span><span class="title-down">К</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>Г</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">Я</span><span class="title-down">Л</span></h2>
        <h3>Я</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>З</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">А</span><span class="title-down">В</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>Ф</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">С</span><span class="title-down">Х</span></h2>
        <h3>М</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>С</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">Б</span><span class="title-down">Х</span></h2>
        <h3>С</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>А</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">С</span><span class="title-down">К</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>Р</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2.5" data-stay="true">
        <h2><span class="title-up">Е</span><span class="title-down">М</span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2" data-stay="true">
        <h3>О</h3>
      </section>
      <section class="js-section" data-zoom-start="2">
        <h2><span class="title-up">О</span><span class="title-down">Т</span></h2>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что вам дебаг браузера говорит? И кстати на каком тестили?

Comment: а почему бы не добавить код в сниппет на сайте

Comment: @Sevastopol' там в логе ошибки в т.ч. загрузки ресурса

Comment: стоит воспользоваться советами из [ответа на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9861/186999) и отредактировать вопрос

Comment: Создайте сниппет с полным кодом на codepen.io а тут добавьте ссылку и минимальный код

Comment: В сниппетах нельзя использовать http протокол, а https, судя по всему на сайте не настроен, поэтому сниппет не поможет, конкретно в данном случае. Делай пример, который воспроизводит ошибку, желательно выкинув все лишнее. Лучшее всего выкинуть старый код, раз нет исходников и написать все заново. Это будет проще чем отлаживать собранный и минифицированный код

Comment: `var canvas = document.querySelector('.Background-canvas');` где этот элемент?

Comment: @Sevastopol' плюсанул, чтобы немного компенсировать издержки на конкурс, удивляюсь, что и отвечающий не сделал подобного, хотя и заработал +125 и щелчок мышкой ему бы ничего не стоил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты подключить в конце страницы в таком порядке

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/jquery.waitforimages.js"></script>
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/script_app.js"></script>    
<script src="http://праздниккрым.рф/script_water.js"></script>
```

svg выкачать себе и заменить адрес в script_app.js , иначе CORS .

Вроде работает, с остальными ошибками лень возиться.

Comment: @Sevastopol' https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-mountain-mdnr7

Comment: @Sevastopol' локально не будет работать, нужно файлы выкачивать, ибо тот же  CORS.
Какие изменения в ответ?